# UILabel dissapearing when going out of his parent view

Tags: objective-c

I'll try to explain my problem as clear as I can:

Imagine that we have a UIView in the middle of our screen, and inside of this view, there is, for ex. a UILabel.

Now I want to move the UILabel out of the view, so I make and animation and change the frame of the label to be out of its view. The problem is that now the UILabel is visible in the other view! I want the UILabel dissapearing when it goes out of the view

```
|  _________  |
|  |       |  |
|  | label |  |
|  |_______|  |
|             |
```

Now I move label to the left

What is happening now:

```
   _________
|  |       |
|la|bel    |
|  |_______|
```

What I want:

```
   _________
|  |       |
|  |bel    |
|  |_______|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that,

```
parentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```